# How can I put a persistent page in flutter which is still touchable while having other pages on top of it

Tags: flutter

How can I put a persistent page in flutter and use the navigator to push new pages on top of it while the bottom page is still touchable if the top pages do not fully cover it.

Example, let's say I have a map which is always in the background and then I can push other pages on top of it to show other things but the map stays in the background and is always touchable.

Tried stack with Navigator